# How can I detect if an iFrame gets redirected to another url?

Tags: javascript, redirect, iframe

I want to list an iframe with a classified ad in it. Sometimes the vendors redirect the page to their homepage when the item is no longer available. I want to be able to identify this so I can de-index the item assuming it has sold. What is the best method to accomplish this?

Comment: From what I can tell, this isn't possible. You can only do this if the iframe refers to content hosted on your domain.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's load function that fires onload or reload.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

You will need to store the number of times the iframe has reloaded.

Something like,

```
var reloaded = 0;
$("#iframe_id").load(function(){
    reloaded++;
});
```

Comment: Really?  This is simply a content loaded event, regardless of the origin.

Comment: seems redirect response does not trigger the load event, only the final  response triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You can not detect the location of the iframe when it is in a different domain unless they have the proper headers set for [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control).

The only way to do it without worrying about the other domain is to have your serverside code run a check on the page and see if it redirects.

Answer (score 0):

On the frame load, detect what the URL is:

```
var frameLoadCount = 0;
var firstURL;

$('iframe').load(function() {
    if (frameLoadCount === 0) {
        firstURL = $(this).attr('src');
    } else {
        if (firstURL !== $(this).attr('src')) {
            // The iframe has been redirected.
        }
    } 
});
```

Basically the above code runs everytime the iframe has loaded, checks if it's the first time, if it is, assign the URL to a variable. If it has loaded more than once, check if the original url matches the current url.

This has benefits from just checking if it's loaded more than once, because you can target specific sources etc.

Comment: Unless they allow cross domain calls. Simply saying "not going to work on another domain" is useless, as it's not correct. It CAN work on another domain, if it's allowed to.

Comment: I bet most sites do not enable CORS by default.

Comment: Yeah, it's really hard to find sites that do enable you to cross domain reference. But it does exist, and simply saying it doesn't will confuse people who are beginning to learn how and iframe works.

Comment: Thanks for your input I thought crossdomain issues might blok it just didnt know if there was a work around.